# Can iperf3 but cannot ping

Tags: ping, iperf3

One access point connected to a pc and one receiver connected to another pc. The access point and receiver are also connected to each other. Both PC have no firewall, security and antivirus.
Both pc can iperf3, send and receive each other. The pc connected to the receiver able to ping the other pc. But the pc connected to the access point is able to ping the receiver but not able to ping the pc connected to the receiver. Why?
The ip address of the pc is 10.23.200.10
ip address of access point is 10.23.200.20
ip address of receiver is 10.23.200.30
ip address of the pc connected to the receiver is 10.23.200.40

Comment: Please add a schema of your network and especially where is situated the router and the models of all the devices. Although the computers might not have firewall, security and antivirus, some intermediate device might be blocking the ping.

Comment: Hi Harry, this is a testing platform. there is no router in between.  the two computers are quite old and nothing different about them. The access point and receiver are our company products without brand. i would just like to keep our company name confidential at the moment.